# Как реализовать опрос множества серверов на erlang?

Tags: сервер, tcp, udp, erlang

Здравствуйте, у меня мало опыта в erlang, но возникла острая необходимость в опросе множества серверов по протоколам udp и tcp. С чего начать, в какую сторону копать? Я начал уже изучать erlang, но многое еще непонятно, в сети очень мало практической информации.

Answer (score 1):

> но возникла острая необходимость в опросе множества серверов по протоколам udp и tcp

Вам нужно будет для каждого сервера создать отдельный процесс, который его будет опрашивать. Процесс удобнее всего создать с помощью gen_server, и подсоединить его как child к какому-нибудь supervisor.

На этом erlang-специфика здесь исчерпывается, в остальном всё будет также как и на любом другом языке.